# HTMLのSELECTのsize指定しても1行で表示される問題

Tags: html

HTMLで、SELECTに、size="20"指定をしたのですが、
WindowsのchomeやIEでは、20行で指定行表示されます。

しかし、iPad、Android Pad、iPhone、Androidでは、
指定を無視し、1行で表示されます。

sizeで指定した行数を表示するには、コツ？があり、どのように記述すればよいのでしょうか？

ググってみましたが、10件程のSELECTの使い方の説明サイトには、
１行で表示されるとは、記述が見当たりません。

※iOSやAndroidが出る前に作成された古いサイトなのか？、
それとも、普通は、iOSでも、Androidでも、20行で表示されるはずで、
下記のsizeの指定方法が間違っているか？
のどちらかかもしれません。

```
<FORM name="form_list_color" method="post" action="next.html">
  <TABLE>
   <CAPTION>２．車の色のリストボックス</CAPTION>
    <TR>
      <TD>
        <!-- sizeは、なぜか？パソコンでしか有効ではない。Padやスマフォは1行になる -->
        <SELECT name="list_color" size="20">
          <OPTION align="left" value="red">   赤色</OPTION>
          <OPTION align="left" value="yellow">黄色</OPTION>
          <OPTION align="left" value="black"> 黒色</OPTION>
       </SELECT>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>

  <INPUT type="submit" name="submit_list_color" value="次画面へ遷移" />
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937203/select-with-size-attribute-iphone-renders-blank
などでも話題になっていますが、iOS などでは select タグの size > 1 は無視されるようです。
自作で作るか、他の方の作ったものを使う必要があります。デフォルトでは不可能です。

jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/sylvain-hamel/safarimobile-multiline-select

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。URLを張っていただきお手数をおかけいたしました。iOSやAndroidで、htmlの基本？SELECTのsizeが無視されるとは驚きです（当然、20行も大きくすれば、画面が小さい古いスマフォなどはユーザービリティーが損なわれる可能性がありますが、今の時代、5行や10行など表示できた方がユーザービリティーが良いこともあると勝手ながら考えています。ですが、iOSもAndroidも両方共、sizeに対応していないことから、1行表示がベストと世界の先頭の技術者が考えているので従うのが普通かもしれません。私は、教えて頂いたjQueryの利用を試みます（著作権があるようなので、どこかに表示しないといけない？ので、悩ましいところですが）。ご丁寧に、ご説明、URLをありがとうございました。大変助かりました。お手数をおかけいたしました。

Comment: 本件、「OSの仕様であり、実現するにはjQueryを使うなどの方法あり」で、『解決』でクローズ しています。

Comment: @JavaScript超初心者 回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックしていただくことで、この回答で解決したという目印になります。「承認」と呼ばれるこの操作がこのサイトの「解決によるクローズ」に相当する操作なので、お試しいただければと思います。(ちなみに自己解決した場合などはご自身で回答して承認していただくこともできます)